# How to access automapper profiles in a shared project?

Tags: asp.net, automapper

I know that to set up automapper in my own project, I just need to use and it will fetch the profiles in my project and use them. But how do I fetch the profiles in a shared project? I understand I need to "add a third party assembler too" but I don't understand how to do this.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

Comment: No, the DI package does it for you. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. So stupid question. How do I figure out the name of the assembly I need in a shared service? I know I'm using reflection to get my own project's assembly...?

Comment: No, the shared project just defines a profile, the main app initializes AM. See https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Configuration.html#profile-instances